# Failed to synchronize ****.com teams with Apple Developer Portal.No such host is known. (Xamarin project).?

Tags: ios, visual-studio-mac, apple-developer-account

**Error : Failed to synchronize ****.com teams with Apple Developer Portal.No such host is known.**

Apple developer account was working fine but on a sudden showing this error while opening Apple developer accounts from preferences

Path--> Visual Studio - Preferences - Apple developer Accounts

Visual studio 2019 for mac-version 8.3.8(build 8)
Xcode- 11.2

Comment: Login in your developer account in Apple developer center and accept new privacy agreement .

Comment: Thodupuzhakkaran already tried this - the issue still persists.
(I'm his college, he doesn't have the right to write comments yet)

Comment: Same issue here, no solution so far...

Comment: You can focus on the link https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/823822/visual-studio-for-mac-version-838-limit-of-request.html

Comment: Solved installing VS version 8.3.10.2

Comment: 2022 still an issue, no answers worked for me. I'm done with this second hand MS garbage, going to learn Swift instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug with Visual Studio for Mac. See [this "closed" issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/825574/view.html) or [a related one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/826310/view.html) on Microsoft's Visual Studio website as well as [a thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/174694/unable-to-add-apple-developer-account-to-visual-studio-for-mac-after-update) on Xamarin forums.

The ["closed" issue page mentions](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/822728/view.html) that as a workaround, you might be able to manually provision by:

- Quit Visual Studio for Mac
- Launch XCode, select Preferences -> Accounts and "Download Manual Profiles" for the account you'd like to use (and/or remove and re-add the account)

  - In my experience, you might even need to create, build and run on a simulator or physical device a dummy project with the same bundle identifier as your Xamarin iOS project
- Quit XCode
- Relaunch Visual Studio for Mac
- Open the Info.plist, select Manual Provisioning and press the "Bundle Signing Options..." button to select the signing identity that hopefully imported correctly

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with VS for mac community 8.3.9 and xcode 11.2.1.

My work around was to add the signing certificate directly from xcode by creating a dummy application and assigning the app bundle to it, after xcode downloaded the certificate I could run my app on VS with no problem.

Cheers.

Edit:

Forgot to add that you have to manually sign it in VS with the corresponding provisioning profile

Answer (score -5):

This issue is solved with latest update of Visual studio for mac.

Updated to- Version 8.3.10(build 2)

Comment: No, it's not.  My VS for Mac is 8.4

Comment: 8.10.8 and I still have this issue

Comment: 8.10 and still having problem