# how i can import ios certificate and provisioning profile on visual studio on xamarin

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i have problem when install the second ios certificate on visual studio

i will to explain what i did step by step .

1 - i have created certificate and provisioning profile from apple developer account by second account , and downlode it on my mac

2 - install the certificate on keychain

3 - create new project on xcode and install the provisioning profile

4 - in xcode it's all work fine , i can build the app and archive it

5 - when i try login the apple id on visual studio by this way ( Visual Studio > Preferences > Apple Developer Account ),
a problem appears below

[image to explain the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSGiZ.jpg)

for more information , 
* the first certificate it work fine on visual studio.
* i entered the bundle identifire name correctly

Is there another way to define the ios certificate on visual studio

Comment: Check with keychain, there is a option to import the key

Answer (score 0):

If you are developer account is the free account, then teams won't appear in VisualStudio but you can see in Xcode.

Follow the below step to test the application in the device.

Open Xcode with demo project.

Set the targeted bundle id in plist.

Select the respected team and choose automatic provisioning profile. So it will generate all the required certificates and profiles and will saves on the Mac.

Run the app in device from Xcode.

Go to VisualStudio, use the same Bundle ID which we used in Xcode to run the app.
Hit run on a device and see the result it will work.

Comment: thank you for answer me ,
but still not work on visual studio.
my certificate is enterprise not a free ,
Do you have another solution?

Comment: go through  this link may it helps you: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/apple-account-management?tabs=macos] 

and this is related question link please check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928366/failed-to-synchronize-com-teams-with-apple-developer-portal-no-such-host-is]

Comment: Thank you, the problem was in an update the visual studio :)

Comment: Updated visual studio resolves your problem. Great !!