# Failed to synchronize abc@xyz.de account with Apple Developer Portal.Failed to resolve forward links for Apple Develop Portal client

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac, apple-developer-account

I'm loosing my nerves with this apple products...

i want to add my Apple Developer Account to Visual Studio for Mac (V8.10.4 Build 11).

But I get this error:

"Failed to synchronize abc@xyz.de account with Apple Developer Portal."
"Failed to resolve forward links for Apple Develop Portal client. Reason: Please check your internet connection or try again later."

Without these I can't load my app to App Store Connect..

My internet connection is working fine, everything else works fine..
My Account was accepted by Apple and I accepted all agreements on App Store Connect.

Please help..

Comment: I am having the same issue since yesterday. It was not refreshing my provisioning profiles, so I removed my account and tried to and it again and the error message popped up. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can try to log in to your developer account in the Apple Developer Center and accept the new privacy agreement.

Comment: I checked the policies all are already accepted.

Comment: Me too, the new privacy agreement was accepted.

Comment: I don't know if they have fixed anything or not, but here is the thing I tried and I got connected again. I just created a new project in visual studio and tried to connect to the apple developer account and it is connected. then I just reopened my other project and everything set up automatically again. Thanks

Comment: @Ingmar you may try this.

Comment: @ShrikantDandile No, this doesn't worked either..

Comment: You can refer to this link：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928366/failed-to-synchronize-com-teams-with-apple-developer-portal-no-such-host-is

Comment: This reference did I tested yesterday, this doesn't solve my problem..

Comment: Here are Normal suggestions for you：
1.Delete all the Provisioning profiles in path ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles.
2.Login your apple account in Xcode - Preference - Accounts , click Download Manual Profiles ,and check valid certificate lists with clicking Manage Certificates.
3.Download the Certificates and corresponding Provisioning profiles separately for your main App and Extension , and click to install.
4.Check if the Provisioning profile is available in Xcode.

Comment: @WenxuLi this isn't helpful when you rely on automatic provisioning to quickly test apps on different devices. In any case, you copy-pasted that from a forum where the error is not quite the same issue as this one.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: @WenxuLi - This is still a problem. Your suggestion doesn't advance a solution. Please try this to recreate - 1.) Create a simple Xamarin solution, 2.) Get it working with a provisioning profile from your Apple account, 3.) Push the solution to Github, 4.) Clone the solution on your Mac, 5.) Attempt to add your Apple Developer Account using Preferences/Apple Developer Account.  It fails. In fact, it even fails to give you an error message. Now do the same thing with a brand new solution. Adding an account works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned by @ShrikantDandile in the comments above. Following worked for me too:

1. Go to Visual Studio -> Preferences -> Apple Developer Accounts
2. Remove existing account
3. Close the solution currently open
4. Create a new app - `TestApp` or something
5. From the menu, go to Visual Studio Select Preferences Under publishing, select `Apple Developer
6. Accounts` Remove existing account and add it back again
7. Close the `TestApp` solution
8. Open your actual solution and you should now see your apple account and profiles in place

Comment: I can confirm that this solution appears to get around the initial problem. It's 2022 and the problem as described by the OP is still happening when I create the Xamarin project in VS 2022 and then clone it on a Mac.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this issue by adding my account to Xcode in Preferences -> Account, and then trying again in Visual Studio.

Comment: Xcode works for me fine. I can even add accounts using VS4Mac 2022 but 2019 doesnt work. it is obviously a bug in VS4mac 2019

Answer (score 0):

Try it through an other Internet Connection like an Hotspot. In my case sth. blocked the login through this dialog. With an Hotspot it worked.

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue, for days, on both my Macbooks and also a Windows laptop running Visual Studio 2022.

The ONLY way I was able cure it was to hot spot to my mobile/cell phone and use its internet connectivity to log in to my Apple account from within VS2022.

Strangely, I had no issue logging into my Apple account from Xcode using my normal household internet.